# Является ли основа слова морфемой?

Tags: морфемика

Является ли основа слова морфемой?

Answer (score 1):

МОРФЕ́МА — минимальная, т. е. не делимая на части, значимая часть слова, или общее определение: миним. двусторонняя единица яз. М. является ключевым понятием морфологии и относится к числу осн. универс. лингвист. понятий.

Гуманитарный словарь [здесь](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%93%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0/)

Основа слова не является морфемой, она часто включает в себя несколько   морфем. Морфемы - это приставка, корень, суффикс и окончание.